# How can i post multiple arrays with JQuery AJAX in an MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My Jquery is

```
 $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var man_data = { 'man': [] };
            var size_data = { 'size': [] };
            var color_data = { 'color': [] };

            $('input:checked').each(function () 
            {
                if(this.name == 'man') man_data['man'].push($(this).val());
                if(this.name == 'size') size_data['size'].push($(this).val());  
                if(this.name == 'color') color_data['color'].push($(this).val());  
            });
            var path = "/Home/Index";
            $.ajax({
                url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
                dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(man_data),
                traditional: true,
                converters: {'text json': true}
            }).success(function (responseText) {
                $('#Grid').replaceWith(responseText);
            }).error(function (responseText){
                swal("Error!", "Test 1", "error");
            });
            //swal("Error!", "Test 2", "error");
        }
    });
```

If i post only one array `data: JSON.stringify(man_data)` it works great.
The problem is that i would like to post the contents of all the 3 arrays

- man_data
- size_data
- color_data

I tried something like

```
data: JSON.stringify(man_data + size_data + color_data)
```

but it is not working as expected :(

How should i modify the code above?

I also tried something like

```
data: {'man':JSON.stringify(man_data),'size':JSON.stringify(size_data)},
```

but now i get the error `Invalid JSON primitive: man.`

**UPDATE**

The data are sent at an MVC controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int[] man = null, int[] size = null, int[] color = null)
{
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something like `man_data.concat(size_data, color_data)`?

Comment: @Dan i get an man_data.concat is not a function error.

Comment: Is man_data definitely an array? Getting is not a function error would suggest that it isn't. Oh i see, it's because they're all wrapped in objects, is there a reason for that? I'll move this into an answer.

Comment: @Dan Actually the data are sent at an MVC controller and the man, size and color are the controller's parameters. I will try the solution of yours of course

Comment: still No luck :( it cannot be that difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the data I would use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

As you are storing your arrays within objects, you'll have to access the properties to get the array before concatenating them. Here I am concatenating the arrays into a new array:

```
[].concat(man_data.man, size_data.size, color_data.color);
```

Unless you are planning on adding more properties to those objects I would suggest just changing them to arrays.

```
var man_data = [];
var size_data = [];
var color_data = [];
```

Like this you can just do:

```
[].concat(man_data, size_data, color_data);
```

Alternatively, instead of concatenating you could just send the data in the following structure:

```
var data = {
  man_data: [],
  size_data: [],
  color_data: []
};
```

Than way all you would have to do is send off that object `JSON.stringify(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data parameter on Ajax call as `data: { 'man': JSON.stringify(man_data), 'size': JSON.stringify(size_data),'color': JSON.stringify(man_color)}`  sorry if code formatting is not correct, I am on mobile.

Comment: Hello, i get JSON.Stringify is not a function

Comment: use JSON.stringify, I had S capitalized which should not be.

Comment: @Chocol8 see if the edit works. otherwise I will check it out once I reach home.